# How can I install gnuplot from this point?

Tags: installation, gnuplot

When I try to install gnuplot from this website, and I extract the .tar.gz file twice, I see the following:
[image]

How do I install gnuplot from this point? Also, where is the 'bin' folder? (As the bin-folder should be located somewhere as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you are installing on Windows.

You don't need to install from source, which requires more packages such as
MinGW or Cygwin.

Use the binary release from the current
[release 5.2.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.2.4/),
choosing the right `.exe` for 32- or 64-bit Windows.

For more info see this
[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47463006/165358).